# Modeling clothes creases/wrinkles

Tags: modeling

How would I go about modeling random wrinkles/creases like in the two photos below?
[image]
[image]

I would like to avoid using sculpt mode but if I have to I will, any help or addon recommendations will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say that you want to avoid sculpting but you probably can't, at least create the folds in *Sculpt* mode then bake the normals? In [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W-N8o5ew-4s), *PixelicaCG* explains how to do this kind of folds. He mainly uses the *Pose* brush with *Deformation Target > Cloth Simulation, Deformation > Squash & Stretch*, and he uses *Face Sets* to preserve some areas from the brush effect (you can use the *Mask* brush as well). Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> to smooth the folds, etc:

[image]